# 'nvcc not found' in NetBeans 8.2 only

Tags: c++, netbeans, nvcc

I'm new to NetBeans 8.2 and the c++ project was built successfully with 'make' command in the terminal but won't build in NetBeans 8.2.

And I had set path of NVCC and it is found when I typed 'which nvcc' in th terminal. It says '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc'

I can build other CUDA example with 'make' command in the terminal, but NetBeans 8.2 is not going to make any CUDA project.

It says 'nvcc: not found'

How can I set nvcc in NetBeans 8.2?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try these steps ?

> how to compile?
>
> Right click on your project and "properties"
>
> In the General tab, uncheck both "C compiler required" and "C++
>   compiler required", select "Generic" in the list box of "Platform"
>
> On the tree select "C/C++"-->"C Compiler"-->"General"
>
> and change the include directories to somewhat like that:
>
> .:/usr/local/cuda/include:/home/patrick/NVIDIA_CUDA_SDK/common/inc
>
> modify to your very path.
>
> and in the "Tool" type nvcc
>
> noe in the "C/C++"-->"C Compiler"-->"Command Line" set these options
>   -v -deviceemu --compile -G0
>
> do exactly the same for the "C/C++"-->"C++ Compiler"
>
> now set the linker, in the same properties box, select
>   "Linker"-->"General", change "Tool" to nvcc

These are the instructions I expect to be the more useful for what you are trying to do.

They can be found on [the devtalk forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/384763/cuda-programming-and-performance/ide-for-cuda-using-netbeans-c-c-ide-with-cuda/1) from Nvidia, for which it might be a little less off-topic than SO.